# Bokeh: Is there a way to set the styling for all figures at once?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I am coding for 20+ tabs to plot similar parameters and have been writing the styling for each figure separately. Is there a way to set the styling all at once for all figures?

```
p = figure(tools=TOOLS, x_axis_type='datetime',plot_height=400, plot_width=700,
           outline_line_color = 'gray',
           y_axis_label = 'Volts',
          y_range = DataRange1d()
          )
# Setting the second y axis range name and range
#p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": Range1d(start=0, end=0.000006)}
p.extra_y_ranges = {"foo": DataRange1d()}

# Adding the second axis to the plot.  
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name="foo"), 'right')

a1=p.line(x='Time', y='340', line_color="darkcyan", line_width=1, source=source)
a11 = p.line(x='Time',y='StdDev', line_color = 'red', line_width=1, y_range_name="foo", source=source)
p.y_range.renderers=[a1]
p.extra_y_ranges['foo'].renderers = [a11]

tooltips=[( "Time", "@Time{%H:%M:%S}"),
        ("Y-value", "$y")]
formatt ={'Time':'datetime'}
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=tooltips, formatters=formatt, mode = 'mouse'))
p.title.text = "Plot Title "
p.title.text_color = "gray"
p.title.text_font = "arial"
p.title.text_font_style = "bold"
p.xgrid[0].grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid[0].grid_line_alpha=0.5
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'TimeStamp'
```

Following my way, I would essentially need to repeat above code 20+ times for each tab.

Comment: Just wrap it into a function that returns `p`?

Comment: Sorry...I do not know why I was thinking about everything else but that!! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome - I've been there!

Comment: Or you could use a [Bokeh theme](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/themes.html)